# Trigger.io: Disable Flash in Camera

Tags: iphone, camera, trigger.io

Is it possible to disable Flash of the Camera by default using trigger.io?

It seems I can't find any option or API Method in File Access and Camera Documentation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Disabling the camera flash is currently **not** supported.  Docs are here -

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/camera.html

However, in theory you could develop your own plug-in to disable the flash -

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/index.html